# NSMutableArray from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have this:

```
NSMutableArray *tableData;
NSMutableArray *thumbnails;
NSMutableArray *prepTime;


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipes" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
tableData = (NSMutableArray *)[dict objectForKey:@"RecipeName"];
thumbnails = (NSMutableArray *)[dict objectForKey:@"Thumbnail"];
prepTime = (NSMutableArray *)[dict objectForKey:@"PrepTime"];
```

And i want to do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:    
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [thumbnails removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

But it fails with:

2013-10-14 16:58:22.202 SimpleTable[8421:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c93012 0x10d0e7e 0x1c92deb 0x1d13c4f 0x29bd 0xd0d34 0x20e97b 0x10e4705 0x182c0 0x18258 0xd9021 0xd957f 0xd9056 0x2a9f4d 0x10e4705 0x182c0 0x18258 0xd9021 0xd957f 0xd86e8 0x47cef 0x47f02 0x25d4a 0x17698 0x1beedf9 0x1beead0 0x1c08bf5 0x1c08962 0x1c39bb6 0x1c38f44 0x1c38e1b 0x1bed7e3 0x1bed668 0x14ffc 0x1ced 0x1c15)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

How to correctly make dictionary into mutableArray?

Comment: try this

tableData = (NSMutableArray *)[[dict objectForKey:@"RecipeName"]mutableCopy]

Comment: What do each of the `objectForKey`s return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[dict objectForKey:@"RecipeName"] mutableCopy] should do the trick!

Edit: You might have to cast it like so [(NSarray *)[dict objectForKey:@"RecipeName"] mutableCopy]

Comment: you are correct, just need to wait 6 min to apply correct answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Kris Gellci, this really did the trick:

```
tableData = [[dict objectForKey:@"RecipeName"] mutableCopy];
thumbnails = [[dict objectForKey:@"Thumbnail"] mutableCopy];
prepTime = [[dict objectForKey:@"PrepTime"] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are removing object twice from tableData

```
    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I should have  Following,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:   
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [thumbnails removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [prepTime removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: Although that is correct, the error says "mutating method sent to immutable object" meaning that he has an NSarray and is calling methods belonging to an NSMutableArray